# Прикрутить к Laravel accordion

Tags: php, css, laravel

Ребята прошу вашей помощи. Нужно прикрутить аккордеон. В backend сделал а на frontend не получается. Как результат проходит только по первому пункту меню. по второму(третьему) пункту тоже проходит, но детей уже не выдаёт. Вроде все работает может просто не хватает класса...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) обычный html

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#sportswear">
                <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                Sportswear
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="sportswear" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Nike </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Under Armour </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Adidas </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Puma</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">ASICS </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#womens">
                <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                Womens
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="womens" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Fendi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Guess</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Valentino</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Dior</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Versace</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#">Kids</a></h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

2) include в шаблон код меню

```
 <h2>Категории</h2>

                        <div class="panel-group category-products" id="accordian">
                            @include('partials._nav')
                        </div>
```

3) код меню  с рекурсией, для вывода вложенных: _nav.blade.php

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    @if($category->children->count() )

        <!-- дети-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#womens">
                        <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                        {{ $category->title ?? ''}}
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="womens" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <!-- рекурсия-->
                            @include('partials._nav',['categories' => $category->children, 'is_child' => true])
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @else
        @isset($is_child)
            <!-- дети детей.. -->
            <li><a href="#">{{ $category->title ?? ''}}</a></li>
            @continue
        @endisset

        <!-- родительские-->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a href="#">{{ $category->title ?? ''}}</a></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

всё элементарно - нужно тоже было указать в foreach на: data-parent

```
    <!-- дети-->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordian" href="#{{$category->id}}">
                    <span class="badge pull-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>
                    {{ $category->title ?? ''}}
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="{{$category->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <!-- рекурсия-->
                        @include('partials._nav',['categories' => $category->children, 'is_child' => true])
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```